# Pass parameter to spool file

Tags: oracle11g, parameters, parameter-passing, spool

Say I have a sql file which is executed from command prompt (SQL Plus), which is working fine.

```
sqlplus dbusername/dbpassword@DBInstance @sqlfilename.sql
```

Now I need to pass a parameter to this sql spool file and according to the value of parameter I should be able to determine the functionality in the sql file. In the below sql code, I need to store the value that I am passing as parameter and in the variable `parameter_Value`

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET DEFINE OFF
SPOOL "Test.log"

var parameter_Value VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    IF(parameter_Value='A')
    THEN
           --do something
    ELSE
           --do something
    END IF;
END;
/

SPOOL OFF;
SET DEFINE ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

Can anyone please help how to perform this task? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage of the word spoolfile is not correct. `sqlfilename.sql` is the sql file or sqlplus file. The output file `Test.log` is the spool file.

you call

```
sqlplus dbusername/dbpassword@DBInstance @sqlfilename.sql A
```

to call the following file

```
SPOOL "Test.log"
DEFINE MY_VALUE=&1

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON


var parameter_Value VARCHAR2(20);

EXEC :parameter_Value:='&MY_VALUE'

SET DEFINE OFF

BEGIN
    IF(:parameter_Value='A')
    THEN
           --do something
    ELSE
           --do something
    END IF;
END;
/

SET DEFINE ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SPOOL OFF;
```

- the substitution of the & variables is a simple text substitution. It can be turned off by executing `SET DEFINE OFF`. The substituion raises information messages by sqlplus that can be turned off by executing `SET VERIFY OFF`
- you should start with the `SPOOL` command, you won't see errors thrown by commands executed before you start spooling into the logfile. This can make debugging tedious. Also you should execute all commands before `SPOOL OFF`
- the parameters in the command line are referend by their position number. I prefer assigning them to a named variable and use the named variable later. This is not necessary. You can use the positional parameter later, too, instead of using a named parameter. But using named parameter makes it easier to change the file if the position of a parameter changes. Also it can document the purpose of the parameter if you choose an appropriate name. I didn't in this example.
- You cannot disable the special property of the `&` character with `SET DEFINE OFF` before the parameter substitution. You have to postpone it until you have done all your substitutions. Otherwise the substitution will not work.
- a bind variable is definded with the `VAR ...` statement in sqlplus. In an SQL text it must be referenced with a preceding colon (:).
- `EXEC statement` is an abbreviation for `BEGIN statement; END`
- be aware that the `--do something` is in a PL/SQL block. So it must be replaced by PL/SQL statements and not by SQL statements or SQL*Plus statements.
  So it cannot be replaced by a `CREATE TABLE ...` statement (this is SQL but not PL/SQL) and it cannot be replaced by a `SPOOL OFF` statement, which is SQL*Plus but not PL/SQL.

Comment: Thats great Miracle. Wll explained :) @miracle173